# Locking Rows in Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to add some feature to my excel worksheet. Basically, what I need is to lock a user from going to the next row unless all data is filled in the previous row.

Example:

Row 7 from columns "A" to "P" need to be filled out completely before the user can go to Row 8

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row <> 8 Then Exit Sub
    Dim N As Long
    N = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A7:P7"))
    If N = 16 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("A7").Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work**!

Comment: @GarysStudent I have put the code into the worksheet as states here, but while filling out Row 7 it still lets me go to like Row 9, 10 and so forth...

Comment: Of course!! ................ your post stated:  "before the user can go to Row 8".............thus row #8 is the **only** forbidden row

Comment: OK sorry about that... allow me to clarify please... no row below row 7 may be edited until row 7 is completely filled out all the way to P column. once Row 7 is complete row 8 and so forth and so on...